# What filesystem allows transferring files between Linux and OS X?

Tags: filesystems, usb, large-files

I have a file that is 12 GB that I am trying to copy from a MacBook Air to a Debian computer, using a USB. I tried formatting the USB in many different ways, such as NTFS, FAT32, OS X Journalizing but either the MacBook Air complained it couldn't copy such a large file, it only had read-only access, or when I formatted it from the MacBook, the Linux computer couldn't recognize the file system.

Is there a file system type recognized by both systems that can be used to transfer large files?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/332315/473234

Comment: @MichaelHomer NTFS support is readonly on MacOS, although there are simple and cheap (or free) tools to provide read-write access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- hfs+ can handle large files, and it *has* write support by Linux.
- Although MacOS has only readonly NTFS support, there are third-party tool for read-write operations with it.
- You can use [split](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) to split a large file into smaller ones. You can later unsplit them with [cat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html). To have a better command line than the MacOS gives you, you can use [brew](https://brew.sh).
- There is nothing what would avoid you to partition an usb drive, except that Windows won't see the extra partitions on hilarious reasons. However, fortunately your current setup ignores the windows trouble.

Comment: exfat-fuse should be viable in that direction too.